# EF Code First from database and updating the model?

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I recently added a database to my ASP.net MVC project using "Create Model from existing database using Code First" and noew I've just added a new column to the database but are struggling with updating my model? How do I do that? I'm familiar with the update using the .emdx-file, but I can't seem to find one.

Thanks!

Comment: I used the "Code first from database" in the Entity data model wizard.

Comment: Well, the idea of code first is that you update the database from code. These "Code first from database" tools are designed to give you a jump start into code-first, not to update a code first model. If you want to work database first, create an edmx from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no edmx file if you used Code First, to update the db you need to use 
[migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) or handle it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Going from memory....

- Dbl Click on the database .edmx file
- Then dbl click the Model tab on the solution explorer.
- Delete the Type from the Solution Explorer
- Right click on the model/canvas area and select Update Model from Database.

Comment: Yep, there is no to be found. I'm used to that appróach, but I can't seem to find any .edmx's.